# cs50 Pset4 problem with blurring an image

Tags: c, cs50, bmp

Have been stuck at this problem for awhile now and I'm very confused as to why my code isn't compiling as it's supposed to. Im supposed to average out the value of colors of pixel number 5 with its surrounding pixel such that the resulting image will look blurred. Here is my code:

```
    // Blur image
    // 1 | 2 | 3
    // -   -   -
    // 4 | 5 | 6
    // -   -   -
    // 7 | 8 | 9
    //assuming i is 5
    void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
    {
        RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                int red = 0;
                int green = 0;
                int blue = 0;
                float counter = 0;

                // 5
                red += copy[i][j].rgbtRed;
                green += copy[i][j].rgbtGreen;
                blue += copy[i][j].rgbtBlue;
                counter++;

                //1
                if (i - 1 > -1 && j - 1 > -1)
                {
                    red += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
                // 2
                if (i - 1 > -1)
                {
                    red += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
                // 3
                if (i - 1 > -1 && j + 1 < height)
                {
                    red += copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
                // 4
                if (j - 1 > -1)
                {
                    red += copy[i][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
                // 6
                if (j + 1 < width)
                {
                    red += copy[i][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
                // 7
                if (i + 1 < height && j - 1 > -1)
                {
                    red += copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
                // 8
                if (i + 1 < height)
                {
                    red += copy[i + 1][j].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
                // 9
                if (i + 1 < height && j + 1 < width)
                {
                    red += copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }

                image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red/counter);
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green/counter);
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue/counter);
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

I check the start with the center pixel and check for the existence of surrounding pixels and average the value of the center pixel using the values of its surrounding pixels accordingly. My code compiles fine and it seems to be working when I run it. When I try to run debug50; all the values add up when I was doing some manual testing. However when i tried implementing Check50, this error message shows up

```
expected "127 140 149\n", not "130 143 153\n"
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
running ./testing 3 0...
checking for output "127 140 149\n"...

Expected Output:
127 140 149
Actual Output:
130 143 153
```

Not too sure what went wrong with my code. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
                //1
                if (i - 1 > -1 && j - 1 > -1)
                {
                    red += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
```

You have used 'j', while it should have been 'j - 1' instead. It should be this:

```
                //1
                if (i - 1 > -1 && j - 1 > -1)
                {
                    red += copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed;
                    green += copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen;
                    blue += copy[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue;
                    counter++;
                }
```

Comment: Could you include information on why you think this will solve the problem?

Comment: I tried that one but unfortunately didnt work out for me too.

Comment: @BoyanHristov I had the same problem so in haste, I thought it was the same here too. I have changed the answer.

Comment: @ffriends_ Did you solve it? Try the current answer.

Comment: @vian yup i solved it. There was one more value that i had to change `// 3
                if (i - 1 > -1 && j + 1 < height)` . j + 1 < height changed to j + 1 < width